# Are technical questions about programs on-topic?

Tags: support, acceptable-question, scope

I would like to understand how Aescrypt works. Since I only know little about cryptography and programming, I wanted to ask a question about how the files are created by Aescrypt?

For example, I would like to know how Aescrypt stores the password/key in the encrypted files.

Would this be on-topic for this SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your exact question, but probably not. Even if Aescrypt happens to use cryptography and happens to be used for security purposes, that doesn't automatically make it on-topic here.

Generally speaking, questions about tools are off-topic, unless they are tools specifically used by security professionals (or by people acting as such). For example, a question about how to use Nessus or Metasploit is likely to be on-topic, whereas a question about how to use SSH or Truecrypt is likely to be off-topic. A question asking how to set up a firewall with a given tool would be off-topic, but a question asking what firewall rules would implement a desired security policy would be on-topic.

“What is the format of an Aescrypt key file?” would be off-topic. It would be on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

An example on-topic question would be “How does Aescrypt protect the confidentiality of the data if the hard disk is stolen?”. It's on-topic because it's about the security implications of how Aescrypt works.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a fair bit on exactly what your question is about. Generally speaking [security.se] is about threat modeling and how to mitigate, respond to, or otherwise protect assets from those threads. Our involvement with cryptography generally revolves around how to use crypto and sometimes cryptographic software, occasionally this drifts more into standard application support issues that would be more appropriate on [su] or [SF]. If you want to discuss cryptographic algorithms or similar then you would be most suited to go to [crypto.se]. While our [FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is not overly verbose on the matter it might be worth a look to get a broader notion of what we're looking for.